# How does jquery mobile hide mobile safari's addressbar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

How does jQuery mobile hide mobile safari's addressbar? I think I need a similar solution,
but i don't want to use jQuery mobile ...

I tried:

http://davidwalsh.name/hide-address-bar

but that doesn't work in my case.

My first child of the body is an absolute positioned div
with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`;

The `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` property seems to cause this problem,
without that property it works fine.

Part of this problem is the address bar always stays in foreground, even if I scroll the page down per hand. this is caused by the absolute positioning.

But, without absolute positioning, "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" doesn't work ...

After a big fight with thousends of lines jquery-mobile code, i ended up with this ;)

**Solution**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!-- viewport -->
        <meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />

        <style type='text/css'>
            body {
                background: #E0E0E0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .page-wrapper {
                width: auto;
            }

            /* native overflow scrolling */
            .mobile-touch-overflow {
                overflow: auto;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                -moz-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                -o-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                -ms-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }
            .mobile-touch-overflow,
            .mobile-touch-overflow * {
                /* some level of transform keeps elements from blinking out of visibility on iOS */
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
            }

            .page-header {
                display: block;
                background: gray;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
                padding: 10px;    
            }

            .page-content {
                padding: 10px;
            }

            .page-footer {
                display: block;
                border-top: 1px solid #CDCDCD;    
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #FFF;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                /*
                * utils
                */

                var utils = {

                    supportTouchOverflow : function(){
                        return !!utils.propExists( "overflowScrolling" );
                    },

                    supportOrientation : function(){
                        return ("orientation" in window && "onorientationchange" in window);
                    },

                    //simply set the active page's minimum height to screen height, depending on orientation
                    getScreenHeight : function(){
                        var orientation     = utils.getOrientation(),
                            port            = orientation === "portrait",
                            winMin          = port ? 480 : 320,
                            screenHeight    = port ? screen.availHeight : screen.availWidth,
                            winHeight       = Math.max( winMin, $( window ).height() ),
                            pageMin         = Math.min( screenHeight, winHeight );

                        return pageMin;
                    },

                    // Get the current page orientation. This method is exposed publicly, should it
                    // be needed, as jQuery.event.special.orientationchange.orientation()
                    getOrientation : function() {
                        var isPortrait = true,
                            elem = document.documentElement,
                            portrait_map = { "0": true, "180": true };
                        // prefer window orientation to the calculation based on screensize as
                        // the actual screen resize takes place before or after the orientation change event
                        // has been fired depending on implementation (eg android 2.3 is before, iphone after).
                        // More testing is required to determine if a more reliable method of determining the new screensize
                        // is possible when orientationchange is fired. (eg, use media queries + element + opacity)
                        if ( utils.supportOrientation() ) {
                            // if the window orientation registers as 0 or 180 degrees report
                            // portrait, otherwise landscape
                            isPortrait = portrait_map[ window.orientation ];
                        } else {
                            isPortrait = elem && elem.clientWidth / elem.clientHeight < 1.1;
                        }

                        return isPortrait ? "portrait" : "landscape";
                    },

                    silentScroll : function(ypos) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            window.scrollTo( 0, ypos );
                        }, 20 );            
                    },

                    propExists : function(prop) {
                        var fakeBody = $( "<body>" ).prependTo( "html" ),
                            fbCSS = fakeBody[ 0 ].style,
                            vendors = [ "Webkit", "Moz", "O" ],
                            uc_prop = prop.charAt( 0 ).toUpperCase() + prop.substr( 1 ),
                            props = ( prop + " " + vendors.join( uc_prop + " " ) + uc_prop ).split( " " );

                        for ( var v in props ){
                            if ( fbCSS[ props[ v ] ] !== undefined ) {
                                fakeBody.remove();
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    hideAdressbar : function(){
                        if(utils.supportTouchOverflow()){
                            $('.mobile-touch-overflow').height( utils.getScreenHeight() );
                        }
                        utils.silentScroll(1);      
                    }

                };//utils end

                // WINDOW LOAD
                $(window).load(function(){
                    utils.hideAdressbar();      
                });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="page-wrapper mobile-touch-overflow">
            <header class="page-header">Header</header>
            <div class="page-content">
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
            </div>
            <footer class="page-footer">Footer</footer>                
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

works fine, tested in android 2.1 & iphone4(ios5+)

there was another Problem with this code, fixed here:
[Hide address bar in mobile Safari when scrolling (touchOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830186/hide-address-bar-in-mobile-safari-when-scrolling-touchoverflow)

Answer (score 10):

**FINAL EDIT, SOLVED**

It has nothing to do with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`, but rather your `height: 100%`. (Don't know why I missed it before).

The only difference between your file is the `<meta>` tag changes outlined below and commenting out `height` in the CSS.

Tested on iPhone 4S/iOS 5.1.

---

**ORIGINAL RESPONSES**

This is what we use:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

It works everytime.

And we only use `addEventListener` since the only phones we care about are webkit based...

---

**EDIT**

Your `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` div shouldn't matter here.  Have you tried placing it 1 pixel down on the page?  Regardless, any scroll down should just cover the top pixel of your absolutely positioned div.

---

**EDIT**

So I loaded one of your examples and this is popping up in the error console: (this doesn't fix the issue, but...)

```
Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored.
/dev/1/:7Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
/dev/1/:7Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
```

Looking at your `<meta>` tag I see:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

You need to use a `,` not a `;`

```
<meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
```

Comment: i linked that solution already! and as i mentioned that doesn't work with "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" and absolute positioning, how about reading the question first ...

Comment: I read that and even updated my answer.  Are you positive you've implemented it right?  I know you linked to it, but I've got mobile pages, live, in production, that I actually copy and pasted that very code from into this answer.  All of those pages, regardless of whatever CSS rules we're applying to the elements contained therein hide the address bar successfully. Have you turned on the console on the phone and looked to see if there are errors preventing your event from firing correctly?

Comment: thx, doesn't work either ... what about the address bar staying always in foreground?

Comment: the event is fired correctly i tested this with a simple js alert, and as i mentioned if i remove the absolute psotioning it works as aspected, i try to export a simple version of my page to jsfiddle, but that will take some time ...

Comment: added some live examples to my question ... maybe you got a link with one of your versions, so i could compare. this must be working, i don't understand why it's not. thx

Comment: @JensT do you want to make a chat?  i see some things that might be causing issuesd

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9143/discussion-between-tkone-and-jenst)

Comment: Sorry, I just checked the "-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch" ability of your solution, and it doesn't perform native scrolling when you remove the "height: 100%", same problem as when you remove the "position:absolute"

Comment: Did you look at the test page I uploaded?  The only line commented out from your test provided was the height.  The scrollbar disappears when the page loads.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: yes ;), but together with native scrolling and not without, your solution disables the native scrolling (fast scrolling) (-webkit-overflow-scrolling), i didn't realised it, first time ... just focused on the adressbar, sorry

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix,  Also you know this only works in iOS 5.1?

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this because I wasted some time debugging this.  The scroll bar will only hide if the page is longer than the viewport.   If your page is too short, and can't scroll, then this code does not hide the address bar.

This is right, no reason to hide if there isn't any content to make space for, but it did take me a couple minutes to figure out why it was working on some pages and not others.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: also when the page is determined suitable for the "Reader" it won't hide right away, giving the user time to click the reader button in the address bar.   I have one page that gets this and others don't, back to Google to find out why...

Answer (score 2):

This is the code JQM uses:

```
// Scroll page vertically: scroll to 0 to hide iOS address bar, or pass a Y value
    silentScroll: function( ypos ) {
        if ( $.type( ypos ) !== "number" ) {
            ypos = $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll;
        }

        // prevent scrollstart and scrollstop events
        $.event.special.scrollstart.enabled = false;

        setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo( 0, ypos );
            $( document ).trigger( "silentscroll", { x: 0, y: ypos });
        }, 20 );

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.event.special.scrollstart.enabled = true;
        }, 150 );
    }
```

Comment: Which, with some added boilerplate, is the same code as above.

Comment: thx for the snippet, seems like tkone is right, so why isn't it working in my case?

Comment: Any content from our site (download our app from the app store!:)) But here's a link http://www.broadcastr.com/item/matthewjohndoyle/this_is_broadcastr/mobile.html

Comment: Yes it is pretty much the same... But that is what he asked for so there it is.

Comment: and i thank you for that ;) testing now how to port this code to native javascript

Comment: Cool I'm glad you found a solution. Good luck!

Comment: @tkone, thanks for your input. Would you mind sharing the snippet on your site that specifically refers to inactivating the up/down/left/right pulling of the page? I'm able to hide the address bar with the code above but would like to do what your site does and inactivate touch movement on the `document.body`. Its a much better UX when the page doesn't slide all around when you touch it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```