# Hide address bar in mobile Safari when scrolling (touchOverflow)

Tags: javascript, ios5, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I want to kind of continue some other Question:

[How does jquery mobile hide mobile safari's addressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798158/how-does-jquery-mobile-hide-mobile-safaris-addressbar)

this hides the adressbar after page is loaded.

But, here my new question:

if i scroll up to reshow the adressbar, the adressbar doesn't hide when you scroll down the page.

so, basically i want to hide the adressbar when the page is scrolling down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

i thought about the scroll position and ended up with this:

```
                    var touchHeight = $('.mobile-touch-overflow').height(),
                        screenHeight = utils.getScreenHeight() - (utils.notStandalone()?44:0);
                    // touchOverflow: hide adressbar when scrolling
                    if(touchHeight > screenHeight && utils.supportTouchOverflow())
                    {
                        $('.mobile-touch-overflow').bind('touchmove',function(){
                            if($('.page-content').offset().top < 0)
                            {
                                utils.windowScroll(1);
                            }
                            return true;
                        });
                    }
```

and here the test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!-- viewport -->
        <meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
        <!-- webapp -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

        <style type='text/css'>
            body {
                background: #E0E0E0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }

            .page-wrapper {
                width: auto;
            }

            /* native overflow scrolling */
            .mobile-touch-overflow {
                overflow: auto;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }
            .mobile-touch-overflow,
            .mobile-touch-overflow * {
                /* some level of transform keeps elements from blinking out of visibility on iOS */
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
            }

            .page-header {
                display: block;
                background: gray;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
                padding: 10px;    
            }

            .page-content {
                padding: 10px;
            }

            .page-footer {
                display: block;
                border-top: 1px solid #CDCDCD;    
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #FFF;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                /*
                * utils
                */

                var utils = {

                    init : function(){
                        var touchHeight = $('.mobile-touch-overflow').height(),
                            screenHeight = utils.getScreenHeight() - (utils.notStandalone()?44:0);
                        // touchOverflow: hide adressbar when scrolling
                        if(touchHeight > screenHeight && utils.supportTouchOverflow())
                        {
                            $('.mobile-touch-overflow').bind('touchmove',function(){
                                if($('.page-content').offset().top < 0)
                                {
                                    utils.windowScroll(1);
                                }
                                return true;
                            });
                        }
                    },

                    supportTouchOverflow : function(){
                        return !!utils.propExists( "overflowScrolling" );
                    },

                    supportOrientation : function(){
                        return ("orientation" in window && "onorientationchange" in window);
                    },

                    //simply set the active page's minimum height to screen height, depending on orientation
                    getScreenHeight : function(){
                        var orientation     = utils.getOrientation(),
                            port            = orientation === "portrait",
                            winMin          = port ? 480 : 320,
                            screenHeight    = port ? screen.availHeight : screen.availWidth,
                            winHeight       = Math.max( winMin, $(window).height() ),
                            pageMin         = Math.min( screenHeight, winHeight);

                        return pageMin;
                    },

                    getWindowHeight : function(){
                        return window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
                    },

                    // Get the current page orientation. This method is exposed publicly, should it
                    // be needed, as jQuery.event.special.orientationchange.orientation()
                    getOrientation : function() {
                        var isPortrait = true,
                            elem = document.documentElement,
                            portrait_map = { "0": true, "180": true };
                        // prefer window orientation to the calculation based on screensize as
                        // the actual screen resize takes place before or after the orientation change event
                        // has been fired depending on implementation (eg android 2.3 is before, iphone after).
                        // More testing is required to determine if a more reliable method of determining the new screensize
                        // is possible when orientationchange is fired. (eg, use media queries + element + opacity)
                        if ( utils.supportOrientation() ) {
                            // if the window orientation registers as 0 or 180 degrees report
                            // portrait, otherwise landscape
                            isPortrait = portrait_map[ window.orientation ];
                        } else {
                            isPortrait = elem && elem.clientWidth / elem.clientHeight < 1.1;
                        }

                        return isPortrait ? "portrait" : "landscape";
                    },

                    windowScroll : function(ypos) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            window.scrollTo( 0, ypos );
                        }, 20 );            
                    },

                    setTouchHeight : function(time) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var footerHeight = (utils.notStandalone())?44:0;
                            $('.mobile-touch-overflow').height( utils.getScreenHeight() - footerHeight );
                        }, time );          
                    },

                    notStandalone : function(){
                        return (("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone);
                    },

                    propExists : function(prop) {
                        var fakeBody = $( "<body>" ).prependTo( "html" ),
                            fbCSS = fakeBody[ 0 ].style,
                            vendors = [ "Webkit", "Moz", "O" ],
                            uc_prop = prop.charAt( 0 ).toUpperCase() + prop.substr( 1 ),
                            props = ( prop + " " + vendors.join( uc_prop + " " ) + uc_prop ).split( " " );

                        for ( var v in props ){
                            if ( fbCSS[ props[ v ] ] !== undefined ) {
                                fakeBody.remove();
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    hideAdressbar : function(){
                        if(utils.supportTouchOverflow()){
                            utils.setTouchHeight(0);
                        }
                        utils.windowScroll(1);      
                    }

                };//utils end

                // WINDOW LOAD
                $(window).load(function(){
                    utils.hideAdressbar();      
                });

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    utils.init();
                });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="page-wrapper mobile-touch-overflow">
            <header class="page-header">Header</header>
            <div class="page-content">
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
                <br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###<br>###
            </div>
            <footer class="page-footer">Footer</footer>                
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does not work on Safari (unable to scroll) and Chrome (just grey screen) on iOS.