# iScroll: How do I hide the IOS Safari address bar

Tags: iphone, css-position, iscroll, address-bar

I'm trying to hide the address bar on my iPhone site. Naturally, I tried this first:

```
 window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
  // Hide the address bar!
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 100);
});
```

Which worked, but...

I went with using iScroll which killed it. I guess that when the absolute positioned elements are removed from the document flow, this effects the height of the body which in turn make the above script useless.

Is there another trick to hide the address bar that is not dependent on the height of the document body?

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798158/how-does-jquery-mobile-hide-mobile-safaris-addressbar

Comment: Thanks. That led me to it eventually.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830186/hide-address-bar-in-mobile-safari-when-scrolling-touchoverflow