# Disable address bar completely like jQuery Mobile iscrollview

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-mobile, iscrollview

I realized that somehow **iscrollview** was able to disable the address bar of Safari completely and make it feels like an app. Even scrolling down, the address bar doesn't show up. As a matter of fact, you CANNOT get the address bar back unless you hit Back or Forward.

**iscrollview:**

https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

I looked at this old thread and it mentioned on jumping to the position that just happened to hide the bar temporarily: [How does jquery mobile hide mobile safari's addressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798158/how-does-jquery-mobile-hide-mobile-safaris-addressbar)

That wasn't what I am talking about. So how did iscrollview disable the Safari bar completely? Anyone knows?

**UPDATE 1:**

This is an attempt to make page's height same as display to scroll only inside. But when I scroll down all the way, it still pulls down the Safari address bar. Basically, `#home` is the `page` and `#main` is the `content` within it. I added this css :

```
#home, body
  overflow: hidden

#main
  overflow-y: scroll
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

This is the JS to change height on the fly:

```
  $('#main').css({
    'height': ($(document).height()) + 'px'
  });

  $(window).resize(function () {
    $('#main').css({
      'height': ($(document).height()) + 'px'
    });
  });
```

Comment: By setting a container to exactly the height of the display I assume and scrolling what is inside the container using iscroll vs native scroll.

Comment: I did that and still not working. See update 1

Comment: You could post this question on the [JQM Forum](https://forum.jquery.com/jquery-mobile) where the author of iscrollview is a daily contributor.